# How to Correctly Setup the Backup and Restore App?

Tags: windows-10, backup, batch-file, cmd.exe

I have asked this question first [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503209/how-to-correctly-setup-the-backup-and-restore-app), but I thought that maybe it is more appropriate here.

Each time I run the `Microsoft Windows` `Backup and Restore` App that is left over since the `Microsoft Windows 7` Operating System, I get an error that some Files are missing and the Backup Process fails.

The Files are actually Folders. I have uninstalled some Apps in the meantime and now there is only one missing Folder that the Backup App does not find.

I have tried to run a Batch File within the `CMD.EXE` Command-Line Processor App with System Administrator Rights:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET DIR1="C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\OneDrive\Pictures\Saved Pictures"
MKDIR %DIR1%
PAUSE
```

The Folder does get created well and nice, but the `Backup` App is still failing.

Could it be a Rights Dead-Lock?

I am creating the Folder using System Administrator Privileges because it is not possible otherwise.

I suspect that the `Backup` App is run with Normal Rights. However, the User Account that I am using is also part of the `Administrators` Group.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this Issue.

The reason why I guess that this is happening is the following one:

The `Microsoft Windows Insider` Program is constantly rewriting the whole `C:\Windows` Folder on each Update, therefore the Folders that are missing have to be constantly recreated.

Earlier, I might have manually started the `Microsoft Windows Backup and Restore` Application and forgot to run the Batch File. The Application might have started to work on the Files and Folders to back up. Then, I might have manually run the Batch File that correctly created the Files and Folders, but that might have been too late - that is, after the Application already considered them as missing. Therefore, the error was happening.

I do not know for sure whether this is the cause for this error since I have encountered it a number of times, not only once, and I do not feel that it was possible to have manually run the Batch File later than needed each time.

Anyway, a possible workaround for this Issue might be the following one:

Create a Scheduled Task that first runs the Batch File and then runs the `Microsoft Windows Backup and Restore` Application. I do not know yet how to tell the Scheduler to automatically run the Application, but I can imagine that it might not be difficult to achieve this goal.

Then, whenever the manual Backup is needed to be performed, one can simply manually run the Scheduled Task. This way, this Issue might not reoccur, at least because the previously suspected behavior should be avoided.

I need to perform the backup manually because I am using Removable Disks as a Third Backup Solution. The First One is the `ASUS Web Storage` Cloud Provider and Synchronizer Application and the Second One is the `File History` Application run on an External Winchester Hard Disk Drive.

If anybody has a better solution for this Issue, then please let me know.